# Sharepoint Search Input box Rendering Issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint

I have encountered a problem in SharePoint using chrome which is that sometimes my site navigation's were not loading so after some Google i found out that there are some problems of rendering Sharepoint Search Input box in chrome. So i hide it and after that my menu's were loading fine.

Now i want my search box to be visible as well. What can i do to make the rendering of search box correctly in chrome ?

Thanks in Advance !